Finding limit of spectral radius to size ratios on a sequence of symmetric matrixes increasing in dimensions
I came across this problem recently:
let $r_n$ be the spectral radius of the $n\times n$ matrix $A_n$ defined by ${A_n}_{(i,j)}=n-|i-j|$, find $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{r_n}{n^2}$$
Intuitively, I guess this translates to maximizing
$$\int_0^1\int_0^1f(x)f(y)(1-|x-y|)dxdy=2\int_0^1\int_0^yf(x)f(y)(x-y+1)dxdy$$
with the constraint on $f:[0,1]\to[0,\infty)$ that
$$\int_0^1f^2(x)dx=1$$
But then I have nothing, not even the area of math I should refer to.
Feels like calculus of variations, but I never took a course on it so I'm not sure. Is it true that this problem is about solving a constrained optimization problem? If it is, which area does it concern? What textbook should I refer to? If it's not, then how should I approach this problem, and again, what area and what textbook?

In which context did you find this problem?

It is a random challenge problem, which is supposed to be on or above graduate level.

It appears that my intuition on the constrained optimization problem was right. And now I have an idea on solving that problem as well.
Using Green's theorem and integration by part, we have
$$\int_0^1\int_0^1f(x)f(y)(1-|x-y|)dxdy=3F^2(1)-2F(1)\int_0^1F(t)dt-4\int_0^1tf(t)F(t)dt$$
where $$F(x)=\int_0^xf(t)dt$$
If we consider variations of $F$ that keep $F(1)$ unchanged only, the Lagrangian (with the constraint) is $$L(F)=-(2F(1)F+4tF'F+\lambda F'^2)$$
Using the Euler–Lagrange equation, we have the necessary condition $$\lambda F''+2F=F(1)$$
Solving this differential equation, we know that $$f(t)=F'(t)=a\sin(bt+c)$$
for some $a,b,c$.
With an educated guess, we come up with $$f(t)=a\sin(bt+\frac{\pi-b}{2})$$
so that $f(t)=f(1-t)$.
Taking the constraint into concern, we have $$f(t)=\sqrt{\frac{2b}{\sin(b)+b}}\sin(bt+\frac{\pi-b}{2})$$
Now we can write $f$ as $f(t,b)$ and define
$$H(b)=\int_0^1\int_0^1f(x,b)f(y,b)(1-|x-y|)dxdy$$
Evaluating the double integral, we have
$$H(b)=\frac{4b-2\sin(b)-2b\cos(b)}{b^2\sin(b)+b^3}$$
Now the problem becomes maximizing $H$.
I computed the numerical value and it matched what I had with the original problem. But I am not sure how to come up with an elementary expression yet.
Differentiating $H$ gives $$b^3\sin(b)-3b^2-b^2\cos(b)+b\sin(b)+b\sin(b)\cos(b)+2\sin^2(b)=0$$
which does not seem to immediately give an elementary expression for $H(b)$. I will update if I have it, or someone else might complete this.
Edit: now I am not so sure that the solution permits an elementary expression, but reducing the original problem into a simple maximization problem allows approximation to great precision with very little time, while approximating the solution by calculating the greatest eigenvalue was very time-consuming and memory-heavy. I could only confidently obtain 6 digits of the solution within reasonable time, but now I can use mpmath to obtain 100 digits instantly:
$$0.6755169434391893120045962367642151087417189029817390796150726168272979491788438624622678938265147469$$
With this, I would like to consider this problem solved for now.
